# Basement Insulation remove or leave

Tags: insulation, basement

In the planning stages of finishing my basement and had a quick question about insulation.

Currently there is foil faced fiberglass insulation on the walls in the basement. After some
Research it seems like the current norm is to use eps or xps foam board. Would there be a noticeable benefit to removing the existing and doing the foam board insulation? It seems like a lot of what I’ve read is subjecting it to the foam performs better against the basement wall in the event of water intrusion through the CBU. We haven’t had any water issues or anything in the basement. I’ve actually never even heard the sump kick on. Any suggestions?

Comment: Where do you live?   How much of your basement is above grade?   Pictures?

Comment: It will cost noticeably more. If a dry basement I would let it stay. Having owned multiple homes with full basements and daylight basements I have not found the insulation to be a noticeable improvement below grade.

Comment: Live in Maryland, DMoore. The basement is a walkout, so entire back wall is above grade and about 3 feet of the 8.5 feet from concrete to floor joist is above grade. When I get home I’ll attach some pictures but what’s there currently is foil faced fiber glass insulation, R5 anchored fo the cbu foundation. It’s original to the house so it’s 30 years old. 

Im leaning toward replacing it but if there’s no real benefit than why incur the additional cost and labor but at the same time better safe than sorry.

Answer (score 1):

The main difference of the different insulation related to the water and moisture is that fiberglass is a fabric with lots of small pieces and lots of open air spaces while the others are solid. Fiberglass can take on and hold moisture and is an ideal place for mold to grow. The solid insulation can not absorb water, and does not allow mold to grow within it which is a very desirable trait in higher moisture situations such as basement walls.

The moisture can and may likely be there and an issue even if there isn't enough water to get to the sump pump. And even if the exterior of the wall and soil is dry, this is because the air in the basement is usually warmer than the concrete basement wall in contact with the cooler ground soil. When moisture in the air contacts the colder surface it can condensate much like water on the outside of a glass of ice water.

I strongly suggest replacing the insulation. It will likely have a higher insulation rating too.

Comment: I really liked this answer because it finally answered something that has been hanging around in the back of my mind for years.

Comment: @michael Karas , you should upvote this answer then. I have had different experiences with insulation and find it not to be worth as much as everyone tends to say it is below grade as I have mentioned in other posts.

Comment: Thanks @EdBeal as MK down voted one of my answers yesterday so I know they vote. Re your different experiences, I'm interested in learning more, will you link one or perhaps direct me to how to locate the comments? I'm fairly new here, thanks

Comment: You cannot answer this with the current info.

Comment: @Ack  Fiberglass itself will not mold. The paper covering can mold. Since this is foil backed I'd leave it.

Comment: It does so indirectly: Per Building Science Corporation RR-0211: Mold—Causes, Health Effects and Clean-up - "Fiberglass... gets dirty, and the dirt grows mold... In addition some fiberglass insulation contains urea based binders that do support mold growth." https://www.buildingscience.com/documents/reports/rr-0211-mold-causes-health-effects-and-clean-up/view.

Answer (score 0):

If you're not having moisture problems in the basement I would urge you to keep what you have. First of all there's cost involved. Foam board is expensive. I doubt you're going to gain anything by changing it out.